# How to make rectangle height fill ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I have the following QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 1024
    height: 768
    visible: true

    ScrollView {
        id:scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle{
            id:rect
            z:5
            color:"red"
            width: 2048
            height: win.height
            border{
                color: "black"
                width: 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code the larger `Rectangle` makes the horizontal scrollbar correctly appear. However, since the scrollbar takes some height from the window, the vertical scrollbar appears too.

How can I make the `Rectangle` fill only available space in my `ScrollView` so that vertical scrollbar won't show up? Using something like `win.height - <someNumber>` is *not acceptable*. Adding `verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff` is also *not acceptable* cause it hides some content on bottom of `rect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking `ScrollView` is not meant for such usage. It is more a container to lay out items and have them shown through the provided scrollbar. Binding loops can pop here and there if bindings are not properly set. Also `Flickable` + a custom scrollbar (e.g. the ones available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833103/how-to-create-scrollbar-in-qtquick-2-0)) can perfectly fit your needs.

That said, `viewport` property provides the desired (cross-platform) workaround for the problem. The documentation states:

> The viewport determines the current "window" on the contentItem. In other words, it clips it and **the size of the viewport tells you how much of the content area is visible**.

Hence the `height` of the child `Item` can be set according to the `height` of the `viewport`. A final simple example with an `Image` (cute kitty incoming) would look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    ScrollView {
        id:scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Image{
            height: scrollView.viewport.height
            source: "http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8582/16489458700_c9d82954b7_z.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]